# JSRuntime windows print how to display all of the records?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server project. One of the requirements is to display records on a popup and then print them as a PDF document. If the records are *too many to fit on one page*, the PDF saves **only as a single page**. I mean only the couple of records that fit on the first-page display on the PDF. How can I make the PDF display all of the records? **Is it due to CSS?**

Here is the modal:

```
     @page "/dialogcard/{Order}"
     @using IMS.CoreBusiness
     @using IMS.UseCases.Interfaces.OrderDetail
     @using System.Globalization
     @inject IViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase ViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase
     @inject DialogService DialogService
     @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
        
     <style>
         .rz-dialog-wrapper {
             left:0;
         }
        
         /*.rz-card{
             margin-top: -1.9rem !important;
         }*/
         .rz-dialog-content {
              
             margin-top: -55px;
         }
            
     </style>
        
     @if (orderDetails != null)
     {
         <div id="printarea1">
             <div class="row my-4">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
        
                     <RadzenCard>
                         <h3 class="h5">
                             Order Date: @Order.OrderDateTime 
                                
                         </h3>
                         <RadzenTabs>
                             <Tabs>
        
                                 @{
                                     var detailVendorId = 0;
                                 }
                                 @foreach (var detail in orderDetails)
                                 {
                                     @if (detailVendorId != detail.VendorId)
                                     {
                                         <RadzenTabsItem Text="@detail.Vendor.Name">
        
                                             <div class="row">
                                                 <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex">
                                                     <RadzenCard Style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                                                         <h3 class="h5">Contact</h3>
                                                         <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                                             <div>
                                                                 <div>Company</div>
                                                                 <b>Vorlance</b>
                                                                 <div class="mt-3">Responsible</div>
                                                                 <b>@detail.Order.DoneBy</b>
                                                                 <div class="mt-3">Vendor</div>
                                                                 <b>@detail?.Vendor.Name</b>
                                                             </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                     </RadzenCard>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex">
                                                     <RadzenCard Style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
                                                         <h3 class="h5">Delivery Information</h3>
                                                         <div class="row">
                                                             <div class="col">
                                                                 <div>Company Name</div>
                                                                 @switch (detail.Warehouse)
                                                                 {
                                                                     case "Shenzhen Warehouse":
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Address</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Contact Name</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Email</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Phone</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "+1233455")</b>
                                                                         break;
                                                                     case "USA Warehouse":
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "Company Name: TRADING LLC")</b>
                                                                         <div>Address</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "1243445,Coconut Creek, FL, ZIP Code: 33073")</b>
                                                                         <div>Contact Name</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "Test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Email</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "gulcin@test.com")</b>
                                                                         <div>Phone</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "+123242422")</b>
                                                                         break;
                                                                     case "Private Shipping":
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "ELEKTRONIK SANAYI VE TICARET LTD. STI.")</b>
                                                                         <div>Address</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Contact Name</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "Test")</b>
                                                                         <div>Email</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "s@test.com")</b>
                                                                         <div>Phone</div>
                                                                         <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "111122")</b>
                                                                         break;
                                                                 }
                                                                @* <div>Address</div>
                                                                 <b>@(detail?.Warehouse)</b>
                                                                 *@
                                                             </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                     </RadzenCard>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
        
        
                                             <RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                                                 Data="@orderDetails.Where(x => x.VendorId == detail.VendorId)" TItem="OrderDetail" Class="mt-3" Style="height:190px">
                                                 <Columns>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="OrderId" Title="Order ID" Width="100px"/>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Id" Title="Product ID" Width="100px"/>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="ProductCode" Title="Product Code" Width="150px"/>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Currency" Title="Currency" Width="95px"/>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="Quantity" Title="Quantity" Width="95px">
                                                         <FooterTemplate>
                                                             <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:G}", orderDetails?.Where(x => x.VendorId == detail.VendorId).Sum(o => o.Quantity))</b>
                                                         </FooterTemplate>
                                                     </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="BuyUnitPrice" Title="Unit Price" Width="100px">
                                                     <Template Context="detail">
                                                         @switch (detail.Currency)
                                                         {
                                                             case "USD":
                                                                 @string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.BuyUnitPrice)
                                                                 break;
                                                             case "EURO":
                                                                 @string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-FR"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("en-FR").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.BuyUnitPrice)
                                                                 break;
                                                             default:
                                                                 @string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("tr-TR").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.BuyUnitPrice)
                                                                 break;
                                                         }
                                                     </Template>
                                                     </RadzenDataGridColumn>
                                                     <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="TotalBuyPrice" Title="Total Price" Width="100px">
                                                         <Template Context="detail">
                                                             @switch (detail.Currency)
                                                             {
                                                                 case "USD":
                                                                     @string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.TotalBuyPrice)
                                                                     break;
                                                                 case "EURO":
                                                                     @string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-FR"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("en-FR").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.TotalBuyPrice)
                                                                     break;
                                                                 default:
                                                                     @string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0}{1:0.#####}",new CultureInfo("tr-TR").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, detail.TotalBuyPrice)
                                                                     break;
                                                             }
                                                         </Template>
                                                         <FooterTemplate>
                                                             @switch (detail.Currency)
                                                             {
                                                                 case "USD":
                                                                     <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N2}", orderDetails?.Where(x => x.VendorId == detail.VendorId).Sum(o => o.TotalBuyPrice))</b>
                                                                     break;
                                                                 case "EURO":
                                                                     <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-FR"), "{0:N2}", orderDetails?.Where(x => x.VendorId == detail.VendorId).Sum(o => o.TotalBuyPrice))</b>
                                                                     break;
                                                                 default:
                                                                     <b>@string.Format(new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), "{0:N2}", orderDetails?.Where(x => x.VendorId == detail.VendorId).Sum(o => o.TotalBuyPrice))</b>
                                                                     break;
                                                             }
        
                                                         </FooterTemplate>
                                                     </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        
                                                 </Columns>
                                             </RadzenDataGrid>
        
                                         </RadzenTabsItem>
                                     }
                                     detailVendorId = detail.VendorId;
                                 }
        
                             </Tabs>
                         </RadzenTabs>
                     </RadzenCard>
                 </div>
        
             </div>
         </div>
     }
        
        
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
             <RadzenButton Click="@((args) => DialogService.Close(false))" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Secondary" Text="Close" Style="width: 120px" Class="mr-1"/>
             <RadzenButton Click="PrintDocument" Text="Print" Style="width: 120px" />
             @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btns" @onclick="PrintDocument">Print</button>*@
         </div>
     </div>
        
     @code {
         [Parameter] public ReportViewModel Order { get; set; }
         IEnumerable<OrderDetail> orderDetails;
            
         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
             orderDetails = await ViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase.ExecuteAsync(Order.OrderId);
                
         }
         private void PrintDocument()
         {
             JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("print");
         }
     }
```

Here is the screenshot of the modal:
[image]

Here is the print preview:
[image]

Here is the related CSS:

```
@media print {
     body * {
         visibility: hidden;
     }
    
     #printarea1, #printarea1 *{
         visibility: visible;
     }
     #printarea, #printarea * {
         visibility: visible;
     }
     .rz-tabview-nav li:not(.rz-tabview-selected) {
         display: none;
     }
     #printarea1 {
         position: fixed;
         left: 0;
         top: 170px;
     }
     #printarea {
         position: fixed;
         left: 15px;
         top: 0;
     }
     button[type=button], input[type=text] {
         display: none;
     }
     .rz-data-grid {
            
         height: unset!important;
     }
       
 }
```

**Edit 1**

I researched, changed the CSS like this but still one page :(

```
.rz-data-grid {
        height: auto !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the browser uses A4 as page size option to print pages and in order to adapt to the size of the page, the browser print preview will auto-hide the overflowed contents. Hence datagrid with large number of columns will be cut off for adapting to the size of the print page.

To print large number of columns, adjust the scale option from print option panel based on your content size.

[image]

When datagrid contains large number of data, printing all the data at once is not the best option considering browser performance. Because rendering all the DOM elements in a single page will produce performance issues in the browser. This leads to slow down or non-responsiveness of the browser. DataGrid has option to handle large number of data by Virtualization. However while printing, it is not possible to use virtualization for rows and columns.

If printing of all the data is still needed, we suggest you to export the datagrid to Excel or CSV or Pdf file and then print it from another non-web based application.

There are many methods and libraries for generating PDF, such as [syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/overview), etc.

Comment: I used itext7 :)